# Почему выводятся все посты вместо одной конкретной

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

В чем проблема? Хочу чтобы при клике на ссылку шел запрос на 3 модели и искал у каждой тот запрос, который я указал. И в зависимости что вернется, должно отображаться на динамической странице. Но при переходе на эту самую страницу я получаю просто тот результат, который я указываю вторым параметром в функции findInModal. Тоесть постоянно рендерятся данные из той модели и все. Я надеялся, что мне будет приходить null при поиске в каждой модели и я фильтровал бы вывод. Но почему-то мне даны все посты сразу. В каждой модели что-то находит и возвращает. Как-то странно!

```
const Tag = require("../models/tag.model");
const Card = require("../models/card.model");
const Post = require("../models/post.model");

function findInModels() {
  const args = [...arguments];

  if (args.length < 2) {
    const result = Promise.reject("Должно быть не менее 2 аргументов");

    return [result];
  }

  const value = args.shift();
  return args.map(model => {
    const modelName = model.constructor.name.toLowerCase();
    const queryParams = Object.defineProperty({}, modelName, { value });

    return model.findOne(queryParams);
  });
}

module.exports.getData = async (req, res) => {
  const { slug } = req.params;
  try {
    const promises = findInModels(slug, Card, Tag, Post);
    const response = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
    const articles = response.filter(article => article !== undefined);
    const article = articles.length ? articles.shift() : null;
    return res.json(article);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: `const response = await Promise.allSettled(promises)` вот тут получается массив массивов статей `[[{},{}],[{},{}]]`, первый элемент этого массива - статьи полученные в рамках первого запроса. можно поднять всё это, вызвав `flat`

Comment: @nörbörnën А можно пример кода?

Comment: @Dmitry [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

В коде ты не правильно работаешь с результатом `Promise.allSettled()`. Вот что пишут в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled#%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5):

> #### Возвращаемое значение
>
> Promise, который будет выполнен после завершения каждого промиса, вне
> зависимости от того выполнился он успешно или был отклонён. В то же
> время, в возвращаемый обработчик промиса передаётся массив, который
> содержит результат каждого промиса в исходном наборе промисов.
>
> Объект каждого результата содержит свойство status. **Если status имеет
> значение fulfilled (выполнено), то объект будет содержать свойство
> value**. Если status имеет значение rejected (отклонено), то объект
> будет содержать свойство reason. Свойство value (или reason) будет
> содержать значение с которым был выполнен (или отклонён) промис.

Кроме того, в коде ты используешь сложный `function.arguments`, который, кстати, deprecated. Вместо него нужно использовать новый удобный и простой [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...`.

Вот что получилось:

<sub>NB: вместо моделей нарисованы объекты-заглушки</sub>

```js
const findOne = async function () {
  return new Array(5).fill(1).map((_, id) => ({ id, _classname: this.name }));
};
const Tag = { name: 'Tag' };
const Card = { name: 'Card' };
const Post = { name: 'Post' };
Tag.findOne = findOne.bind(Tag);
Card.findOne = findOne.bind(Card);
Post.findOne = findOne.bind(Post);

function findInModels(value, ...models) {
  if (models.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('Модели должны быть указаны');
  }

  return models.map((model) => {
    const modelName = model.name.toLowerCase();
    return model.findOne({
      value, modelName
    });
  });
}

async function getData(req) {
  const { slug } = req.params;
  try {
    const promises = findInModels(slug, Card, Tag, Post);
    const response = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
    const articles = response.reduce((acc, item) => {
      if (item.status === 'fulfilled') {
        acc = acc.concat(item.value || []);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
    const article = articles.shift();
    console.log(article);
    console.log(articles.length);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

getData({ params: { slug: 'ab' } });
```